# mysql - How to query for items sold within 12 months of each other

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table of sales transactions and I've been asked to report only on items that have two sales within a 12 month period. For example:

```
id | Item | Sale Date
---------------------
1  |  A  | 2017-02-03
2  |  C  | 2016-05-04
3  |  A  | 2016-08-23
4  |  B  | 2016-03-25
5  |  D  | 2015-07-30
6  |  A  | 2013-04-19
7  |  E  | 2011-03-12
8  |  B  | 2017-05-20
9  |  E  | 2011-05-04
```

Item A has three sales records, but only transactions 1 & 3 should be returned as transaction 6 is more than 12 months from transaction 3.

Item B has two sales, but greater than 12 months apart so should be excluded.

Item E has two sales within 12 months of each other so should be included.

I'm using this to find entries with multiple sales:

```
SELECT * FROM salesdata.sales
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Item_Code, COUNT(*) c from salesdata.sales
    GROUP BY Item_Code HAVING c > 1)  as vals
ON sales.﻿Item_Code = vals.Item_Code;
```

But can't figure out how to test if the two sales for an item are within 12 months of each other.

Comment: What is your expected output?  Do you just want a list of items or do you want actual records?

Comment: The actual records would be preferred, there's a bunch of other columns for each item I'll need to include in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM my_table x 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.id <> x.id 
            AND y.item = x.item 
            AND DATEDIFF(GREATEST(y.sale_date,x.sale_date),LEAST(y.sale_date,x.sale_date)) < 365;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of items that have had a sale within the previous 12 months:

```
select s.*
from salesdata.sales s
where exists (select 1
              from salesdata s2
              where s2.item_code = s.item_code and
                    s2.sale_date >= s.sale_date - interval 1 year and
                    s2.sale_date < s.sale_date
             );
```

Your question is unclear what you want to do with this information, but this retrieves all items.

Comment: Gordon: What about the _first_ or earliest item?  It might not have a backward 12 month sale but only a forward sale, yet it should still be included.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . If an item item has two sales within 12 months of each other, it doesn't matter which you take -- one is within 12 months before and the other is within 12 months after.  This query gets the second one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.*
from salesdata.sales s
INNER JOIN (
SELECT COUNT(item), item
FROM salesdata.sales
WHERE Sale Date >= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
GROUP BY item
HAVING COUNT(item) > 1
) b
on s.item = b.item
and s.Sale Date >= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```